# How can I solve this mysql search query

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I'm working on a chained select drop down that pulls data from the database to populate the category combobox while the subcategory combo box populates when an option from the category combobox is selected. The category dropdown box pulls data from database without any issue but I am having problems with getting the subcategorycombo box select data from database based on the 'id' of the option selected in the category combo box.Any help pls?below is my php code and the jquery code that display the data

```
 <?php 
    include ('../storescripts/connection.php');

      function ShowCategory(){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM category";
   $res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
   $category = '<option value="0">Choose...</option>';
     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
     {
         $category .= '<option value = "'.$row['category_id'].'"> '.$row['category_name']. ' </option>';
         }
         return $category;
   }

   function ShowSubCategory(){
         if (!isset($_POST['id'])) 
        {
        //If not isset -> set with dumy value 
        $_POST['id'] = ""; 

            } 

       $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM subcategory WHERE category_id = '$_POST[id]'";    
       $res1 = mysql_query($sql1) or die(mysql_error());   
       $subcategory = '<option value="0"> Choose...</option>';
       while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res1)){

             $subcategory .= '<option value="'.$row['subcategory_id'].'"> '.$row['subcategory_name'].' </option>';

           }
           return $subcategory;
       }

?>
```

//jquery code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {

 $("select#category").change(function(){
var id = $("select#category option:selected").attr('value');
 $.post("select_subcat.php", {id:id}, function(data){
    $("select#subcategory").html(data);
    });
 });

 });
 </script>
```

Comment: Out of curiosity: did you format the code that way? Do you think it is readable?

Comment: Let me introduce you to a friend of mine called [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: sorry Gordon I'm quite new here..So am still getting use to the code formatting..

Comment: if this helped you answer you question, please mark it as answered! :)

Answer (score 2):

Try to narrow down what could be the problem. Have PHP print out the SQL statements to the page when you make a selection.

Then you can feed that exact statement into MySQL (through command line or via phpmyadmin) and see if you get the results you want. If you do, then the problem is later down the line. What do you see?

I will agree with earlier poster - if the $_POST id is not set, you fill it with ""? That probably won't get any results.

One last note: at very least use [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) before you ever touch any $_POST or $_GET variables. You are opening your site up to a number of SQL injection attacks otherwise.

Comment: am not sure what to fill the $_POST id with because actually I like to fill it with the category_id of the category selected from the category combo box but i am not sure how to solve this issue. secondly the sql statements don't work too I have tried printing it on a page

Comment: Please acknowledge you are now aware of `mysql_real_escape_string`. You are playing with fire here and you will get burned.

Comment: @uzeeOnCodes well if print the SQL statements don't work, you should get an SQL error, giving you a hint about what is wrong with your syntax. again, with the empty ID you won't get any results, even if your syntax is correct. as for POST, you have to fill that using an HTTP POST request - read here if you don't know what that is: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP), it is just key/value pairs  passed to your script